# Why does this code that reverses an integer print 'inf'?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to print the reverse of an integer using Python. I would expect the output of `345` to be `543` (i.e., `345` reversed), but instead, I get `inf`.

Here's my code:

```
def intreverse(n):
    r = 0

    while n != 0:
        d = n % 10
        r = r * 10 + d
        n = n / 10

    print(r)

intreverse(345)
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Side note: converting to string, reversing and reconverting to integer is way easier

Comment: @user8408080's comment in code: `intreverse = lambda i: int(str(i)[::-1])`

Answer (score 3):

As said above, you need integer to integer division.

Replace

```
n = n/10
```

by

```
n = n // 10
```

`//` divides to `int` and not `float`.

Answer (score 1):

If I may, your problem can be solved without any math at all

```
def intreverse(n):
    return int(str(n)[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that division with `10`, implicitly convert `n` to `float`. The assumption is that `n` is an integer.

Change,

```
n=n/10
```

to (prevent implicit convertion to `float`),

```
n=int(n/10) or n=n//10
```

---

*n.b. The original problem is that you do have `float` conversion and then your exit condition `n!=0` is not satisfied as you expect due to floating point inaccuracy.*

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to make the number into an array.

```
def reverse(number):
    listing = []
    intversion = ""
    for letter in str(number):
        listing.insert(0, letter)
    for x in range(0, len(listing)):
        intversion += str(listing[x])
    print(int(intversion))

reverse(345)
```

The output would be as following:

```
543
>>>
```

Note - The variables that I used can be changed to whatever you like, except `letter`.

Comment: Hi John! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your answer to make sure that your indentation is right. Thanks!

Comment: This is the overcomplicated version of `int(str(i)[::-1])`, basically. Also what you are doing is effectively rewriting the standard functions `reversed` and `join`

Comment: oh well I'm new to python I don't know how to use those yet so that's how I've always done it

Comment: @JohnLiu no problem mate; didn't mean to sound rude or anything. Just said this, so you know it for the future. It may be a good idea for you, to read about the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) and [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) have a nice day :)